# Keras BatchNormalization, What exactly is sample wise normalization?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am trying to figure out what exactly the batch normalization in Keras does. Right now I have the following code.

```
for i in range(8):
    c = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode = 'same', init = 'he_normal')(c)
    c = LeakyReLU()(c)
    c = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode = 'same', init = 'he_normal')(c)
    c = LeakyReLU()(c)
    c = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode = 'same', init = 'he_normal')(c)
    c = LeakyReLU()(c)
    c = merge([c, x], mode = 'sum')
    c = BatchNormalization(mode = 1)(c)
    x = c
```

I set the batch norm mode to 1 which according to the Keras documentation `1: sample-wise normalization. This mode assumes a 2D input.`

What I think this should be doing is just normalizing each sample in the batch independently of every other sample.  However when I look at the source code for the call function I see the following.

```
    elif self.mode == 1:
        # sample-wise normalization
        m = K.mean(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        std = K.std(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        x_normed = (x - m) / (std + self.epsilon)
        out = self.gamma * x_normed + self.beta
```

In this it is just computing the mean over all of `x` which in my case is `(BATCH_SIZE, 128, 56, 56)` I think.  I thought it was supposed to normalize independent of the other samples in the batch when in mode 1.  So shouldn't `axis = 1`?  Also what does "assumes a 2D input" mean in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this it is just computing the mean over all of x which in my case is `(BATCH_SIZE, 128, 56, 56)` I think.

By doing this you are already violating the contract of that layer. That is not a 2 dimensional but a 4 dimensional input.

> I thought it was supposed to normalize independent of the other samples in the batch when in mode 1

It does. `K.mean(..., axis=-1)` is reducing axis -1 which is synonymous for the last axis of the input. So assuming an input shape of `(batchsz, features)`, axis -1 will be the `features` axis.

Since `K.mean` is very similar to `numpy.mean` you can test this yourself:

```
>>> x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> x
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> np.mean(x, axis=-1)
array([ 2.,  5.])
```

You can see that the features got reduced per sample in the batch.

Comment: nemo can you clarify what you mean by "violating the contract of that layer."?

Comment: I mean the preconditions (and other conditions) that the layer defines, one of them is the expected input dimensionality which was not followed in this case.